# Why does CoreMotion authorization message appear in background in iOS 8 "<APP> Would like to access your motion activity"

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios8, core-motion

I have an app that uses a CoreMotion Pedometer in iOS 8, and at first lauch, the app appears to freeze up until one presses the home button.

Upon exiting to the home screen, the app then shows a message " Would like to access your motion activity". And if you press ok and go back into the app, everything works fine.

What I want to understand is why the OS is asking this message in the background. Why should I have to first exit the app, answer the dialog, and then go back into the app. In the past, this dialog box would pop up inside the app and the user could press okay and continue. Is this some iOS8 specific functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Try putting the corresponding code into -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;.